# MoveFile not resetting creation time attribute of file in original location after being moved

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, file-properties

I am trying to call MoveFile to move a file to a new directory. Then make a new file with same name in the location it was moved from. I want the creation time attribute of the new file to be set to whatever the time is at the time the new file is created. I expected this would be the normal behavior when using MoveFile. But for some reason it keeps setting the creation time to the creation time of the old file.

```
FILE* m_pFile;

::MoveFile(bstrRequestedFile, bstrTimestampLogFile);

m_pFile = ::_wfsopen(bstrRequestedFile, L"wt", _SH_DENYNO);
```

When I step through the code slowly or add a sleep between the Move and open lines the creation time will be current when the file is opened. I'd like to avoid the sleep if possible. Also I have tried things like SetFileTime but was not working for me. The file is getting moved successfully and does not show in the original location until the open line.

Comment: You can remove the C language tag, the C language doesn't have the scope resolution operator, `::`.  Your example is C++.

Comment: I recommend searching the internet for "C++ MSDN MoveFile" and read carefully.

Comment: This is known as [filesystem tunnelling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923) and is a "feature".